# Solve this non-homogenous recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$a(n) = a(n-1) + 3*a(n-3) + 2n$$
I have tried solving through characteristic equation,  but impossible to find roots of cubic equation. Any other method?

Comment: This problem has come up repeatedly over the last day or so.  What is its source?

Comment: Cubics do have roots.  Why can't you find them?

Comment: Should it not be $$a_n=a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}+2n$$?